# Composition of functions is injective implies the functions are injective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have reason to believe the following proof is flawed, but I am not able to pin down the inconsistency.

Let $f:A \to B$ and $g:B \to C$ and the composition $g \circ f : A \to C$ be injective.

Let $a_1$ and $a_2$ be some elements in $A$ such that $a_1 \neq a_2$. As the composition is injective, we know also that $g(f(a_1)) \neq g(f(a_2))$.

Assume for the sake of argument that $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$. By definition, $g$ is a function and so the image of $f(a_1)$ and $f(a_2)$ under $g$ must be equal if $f(a_1)$ and $f(a_2)$ are equal. However, this would contradict our assumptions. Thus $f(a_1)$ and $f(a_2)$ must be distinct. This implies that $g$ is injective.

Assume that $f$ is not an injection. In other words, there exists some $a_1,a_2 \in A$ such that $f(a_1) \neq f(a_2)$ and $a_1 = a_2$. However, we know that $g$ is an injection, so the image of $f(a_1)$ and $f(a_2)$ under $g$ are distinct. But, since the composition is injective, we must also have $a_1 \neq a_2$, which is a contradiction. Thus $f$ is an injection.

My suspicion is:

- In attempting to show that $g$ is injective, I have only shown that for some elements of $B$ (the image of $f$) we have the needed condition, but I must in fact show that it holds for any arbitrary element of $B$. Would the proof hold under the additional condition that $g$ is surjective?

Comment: Your paragraph (the one beginning: "*Assume for the sake of argument that $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$*") is great except for the last statement. The paragraph's reasoning shows that $f$ is injective.

Comment: Your suspicion is correct and as noted already, you proved $f$ is injective, not $g$. The proof would be correct, i.e. would show $g$ injective, if *$f$ were surjective*. Notice that if $g$ were surjective and $f$ were not, $g$ might not be injective on the part of B not in the image of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

If $g \circ f$ is injective, then $f$ is necessarily injective: for if $f(a)=f(b)$, then $g \circ f(a)=g \circ f(b) \Rightarrow a=b$.

$g$ needn't be injective when $g \circ f$ is: if $f,g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ where $f(x)=\mathrm e^x, \, g(x)=x^2$, then $g \circ f (x) = \mathrm e^{2x}$; $g \circ f$ is of course injective.